# Java : How to use the `Comparator` interface

Tags: java, object, comparator, compareto

```
private class myComparator implements Comparator<Object>{

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object obj1, Object obj1) {


            if ((obj1.getNumber() - obj2.getNumber()) == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            if ((obj1.getNumber() > obj2.getNumber())  { 
                return 1;
            }

            return -1;
        }
```

Hey I have no idea how to implement this compareTo method in a Comparator class that I'm implementing. I'm trying to compare the two objects integer values that to ascending order. But I'm really not sure where I go

Later, I will be calling this class as collections.sort(someList, myComparator) within another class.

Comment: Have you tried at least *compiling* this?

Comment: ***private Class !!!*** Are you sure ?

Comment: Since your comparator is of the type **<Event>**, your **obj1** and **obj2** objects should be explicitly declared as **Event** objects, and not **Object** objects

Comment: @NeerajJain Inner classes? Do you know what they are?

Comment: Sorry guys big mistake - "comparator is of the type <Object>" and null checks can be assumed.

Comment: I am voting the close this question as unclear since the OP is clearly not sure what their requirement really is. Editing a question and changing its meaning drastically after people have already spent efforts answering it is bad form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your edit, your `Comparator` now takes an `Object` type. The same rules explained below will apply for your `Comparator<Object>`. However, you will not be able to call the `getNumber` method without explicit casting since object does not have any such method.

---

You should take note of the following points if you are using a `Comparator`

1. You implement the `Comparator<Event>` interface. This means that you want to compare two `Event` objects.
2. A `Comparator` does not have a `compareTo` method. It has a `compare` method that will take two parameters of the type of `Comparator` that you are implementing. Since you implement `Comparator<Event>`, your `compare` method should take 2 `Event` arguments.
3. Read the `java-doc` for the [compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)) method in `Comparator`. It explains what the `int` return value represents. If `getNumber` returns a number, avoid subtraction or you may be a victim of overflow.
4. You have declared `myComparator` to be a `private` class. This is permissible only if `myComparator` is an inner class.

I have deliberately not provided the corrected code as I want to avoid spoon feeding you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Comparator` requires a `compare` method, not `compareTo`. And since your class implements `Comparator<Event>`, the arguments of the method should be `Event`s.

```
private class myComparator implements Comparator<Event>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Event obj1, Event obj1) {
        if (obj1 == null) {
            if (obj2 == null) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } else if (obj2 == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return obj1.getNumber().compareTo(obj2.getNumber());
    }
}
```

Note that I'm assuming `getNumber()` never returns null. If it can return null, more null checks are required.

Comment: I think **private modifier** is not allowed .

Comment: @NeerajJain That is an inner class. Are you sure you understand Eran's answer?

Comment: @ChetanKinger and why you think it's an inner class ?

Comment: @NeerajJain Why do you think it's not? When you see `private` in front of a class, you should assume it is an inner class. You should not be downvoting a good answer just because you don't want the class to be an inner class.

Comment: @NeerajJain - `private` , `public` don't matter here. *Eran* just modified the OPs original code. I don't think this answer should be down-voted because of that issue

Comment: @ChetanKinger , Sorry to say but ***Assumptions lead to miscommunication*** , any way leave it , it's already upvoted

Comment: @TheLostMind , understood and it's Up :)

Comment: @NeerajJain How ironic. Aren't you the one making assumptions in the first place?

Comment: Sorry guys big mistake - "comparator is of the type <Object>" and null checks can be assumed.

Comment: @Josh123 Object doesn't have a `getNumber()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Object doesn't have getNumber method. As you already using Generics, you compare method signature should be:

```
public int compare(Event obj1, Event obj1) {
                  ^^
```

With Comparator you need to override compare method and not compareTo.

And now you can use getNumber on event object. Also you should not use number1 - number2 as it may cause number overflow, and hence i would suggest you using something like:

```
num1<num2 ? -1 : (num1==num2 ? 0 : 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparator interface doesn't have *compareTo* method. It has *compare* method instead.
Second thing, since you are Comparator is generified with Event type class/interface, change the method signature to follows.

public int compare(Event obj1, Event obj2) {

}

General rule, If two objects are equal then return 0, If first object is greater than second[in comparison logic] then return 1 else return -1.